# Problem using Observable.combineList of RxJS in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, rxjs

I want to use the typscript function to have to Oberservable sync.

First I have a service, which gives me the Oberservable as return.

```
  public updatePlayers(players: Player[]): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(this.REST_URI + "player/updateplayers", players).pipe(
      tap(_tap => console.log("Update Players. " + _tap)),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }
```

Than I have the function where I want to use the Observable.combineList to wait for booth function to be finished with the update.

```
OnSubmit(){

   let updateAllPlayers = combineLatest(this.restApi.updatePlayers(this.allPlayerTeam1), this.restApi.updatePlayers(this.allPlayerTeam1));
    updateAllPlayers.subscribe((teamxx1, teamxx2) => {
      this.router.navigate(['statsRecordGrid', this.team1.id, this.team2.id]);
    }, (e) => {
      console.error("Players not updated");
    });

}

....
}
```

I get this error:

> ERROR in players/players.component.ts(91,22): error TS2339: Property
>   'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<{}, [{}, any,
>   any]>'.

Which I do not understand because if I also do the example of RxJs with the timer I geht the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have imported the lettable operator instead of the function. Update the import of `combineLatest` to be:

```js
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: Create yes I had to imporant it. Now I have this Problem:ERROR in players/players.component.ts(91,32): error TS2345: Argument of type '(teamxx1: any, teamxx2: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: [any, any]) => void'. Okay i think I can only do subscribe( (a) =>..... )

Comment: Yes combineLatest maps the latest result of each observable to an array of their values in order. Your subscribe will need to be something like this: `updateAllPlayers.subscribe(([teamxx1, teamxx2]) => { /* ... */ });`